# Creating 2D Bounding Box's

Tags: java, android

how would I create a bounding box around a object if I am using the canvas surfaceview? Would I have to do it in the object class? Inside of my view class? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it inside your view class, you could have a Rect instance called boundingBox or somthing, then have a meathod called checkBounds(int x, int y) that returns a boolean, then inside the checkBounds meathod just do:

```
if(boundingBox.contains(x,y))
{
    //put code here that moves a character or somthing
}else{
    //put code here that says a character cannot move or somthing
}
```

so that way the meathod can be called from a bunch of different places.